# MySQL: What happen when an executing sql's client is terminated?

Tags: mysql

Executing long-time sql like

```
UPDATE ACC SET A = 'EE' WHERE A IS NULL
```

then I found I made a mistake, so I kill my client. When I restarted client and executed another sql, like

```
UDPATE ACC SET A = 'EE' WHERE ID = 1888
```

but I got error:

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.

I searched this error and found it was caused by uncommitted transaction holding locks. My question is:

1. Can close client connection stop sql execution?
2. If quesion 1's answer is NO, when sql query finished but client disconnected, will MySQL commit the result?

Comment: After client restart, before starting another query, you must find your previous session (its number) using `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and kill it. Closing connection do NOT stops query execution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that killing the *client* won't be noticed by the *server* until the server sends data to the client.  That is, the server will finish the query.

`COMMIT` happens in different ways.

- `BEGIN; UPDATE...; <client dies>` -- has not gotten to `COMMIT`, so no commit.
- `autocommit=OFF ... UPDATE ...` -- same as above
- `autocommit=ON ... UPDATE...; <updated finished, so committed> (I think)`